# Exception while using Protobuf converter in Retrofit ? I am trying to deserialise Json response using proto buf

Tags: retrofit, protocol-buffers

>

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
        at retrofit2.converter.protobuf.ProtoResponseBodyConverter.convert(ProtoResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
        at retrofit2.converter.protobuf.ProtoResponseBodyConverter.convert(ProtoResponseBodyConverter.java:26)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:116)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
        at com.testing.InvokeTestingPOS.main(InvokeTestingPOS.java:31)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
        at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidWireType(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:99)
        at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:515)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessage.java:205)
        at json2pb.TestingInfo.<init>(TestingInfo.java:61)
        at json2pb.TestingInfo.<init>(TestingInfo.java:9)
        at json2pb.TestingInfo$1.parsePartialFrom(TestingInfo.java:131)
        at json2pb.TestingInfo$1.parsePartialFrom(TestingInfo.java:126)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:192)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:209)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
        at retrofit2.converter.protobuf.ProtoResponseBodyConverter.convert(ProtoResponseBodyConverter.java:38)
```

Comment: Please post your code@Pradeep Mallika

Comment: Hi @Matteo,

Thank you for your interest.I am bit hesitant for sharing my code ,if you have any examples code for using Protobuf convertor in Retrofit  for deserialising json means pls share it, thanks in advance. If code is necessary to you to help mean, i will preparing code flow with  some publicly available api.

Pradeep